# How to write German umlauts to a spreadsheet with xlsxwriter in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I already tried this one, but when I open the Excel spreadsheet, the whole Excel file is blank. Is there another way?

```
import xlsxwriter

....
    sheet.write(1, 27, "Französisch".decode('latin1'), bold)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel, and XlsxWriter, use either ASCII or UTF-8. To write a string like that in Python 2:

1. Encode the file as UTF-8.
2. Include the "coding" directive at the start of the file.
3. Use u'' to indicate a Unicode string.

Like this:

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('B3', u'Französisch')

workbook.close()
```

[image]

In Python 3 you just need to encode the file as UTF-8.

See the [Unicode examples in XlsxWriter docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your question did a little research and found an example.

```
import xlsxwriter


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hallo')

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'Welt', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'logo.png')

workbook.close()
```

Should be working ;)
For further information visit: [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter)

Comment: Can you add the example from the question with the accented character? Does it still work?  Your examples are not compelling because the words use plain ASCII characters, whereas it is virtually certain that the accented ö (o-umlaut, U+00F6, LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS) is the source of the trouble.

Comment: Just to confirm, the example does not work if you add for instance "Französisch".

Comment: # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-


just put this line in the first row before import xlsxwriter ;)

Comment: I assume from the smiley face that that's supposed to help somehow?

Comment: yes should work now because if you set the coding like this it takes the iso from germany with all the ö ü and ä